# Prompt user to choose from menu

Tags: c++, linux

The following code simply prompts the user to choose from a menu, and then it displays the choice made by that user.

It only accepts input consisting of a single digit between 1 and 6, inclusive.  Anything else will be considered as being invalid.

**Questions**

1. While it considers Ctrl-D as an invalid choice, should it be handled differently?  If so, how?
2. It takes user input as an `int`.  Would you suggest taking it as a `string` instead, and then use either `stoi` or `stringstream` to convert it to an `int`?
3. Can it be re-written in a more elegant and concise way?
4. Do you see any potential issues?
5. Any comments?

**Source Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int getChoice()
{
    std::cout << "Main Menu\n"
        << "-------------------\n"
        << "1. Add record\n"
        << "2. Edit record\n"
        << "3. Delete record\n"
        << "4. View record\n"
        << "5. View all records\n"
        << "6. Exit\n";
        

    bool isValid;
    int choice;

    do
    {
        isValid = true;
        std::cout << "Enter choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            if (std::cin.eof())
            {
                std::cin.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            if (std::cin.gcount() > 1)
            {
                isValid = false;
            }
            else if (choice < 1 || choice > 6)
            {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        if (!isValid)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid choice\n";
        }
    } while (!isValid);

    return choice;
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    choice = getChoice();

    std::cout << "User chose option " << choice << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input and Results**

```
Main Menu
-------------------
1. Add record
2. Edit record
3. Delete record
4. View record
5. View all records
6. Exit
Enter choice: x
Invalid choice
Enter choice: 8
Invalid choice
Enter choice: 2x
Invalid choice
Enter choice: x2
Invalid choice
Enter choice: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Invalid choice
Enter choice: 888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
Invalid choice
Enter choice: Invalid choice // Ctrl-D entered here
Enter choice: ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./getchoice_cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> While it considers Ctrl-D as an invalid choice, should it be handled differently? If so, how?

You should treat the end of the file as the definite end of the input, and return immediately with a value that indicates a failure. Not all EOFs are Ctrl-D's, there is no guarantee that you can even continue reading from `std::cin` after you encounter an EOF; for example the user might have redirected standard input to a file.

> It takes user input as an int. Would you suggest taking it as a string instead, and then use either stoi or stringstream to convert it to an int?

As you have probably seen `std::cin >> some_int` does not read a whole line, instead it tries to read an integer but stops as soon as it encounters something that is not an integer. Instead of fighting against this, use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) if you want to read a line, and then indeed use `std::stoi()` or something similar to convert that to a number. You still need to deal with the fact that also `stoi()` stops as soon as it sees the first character that is not part of an integer.

> Can it be re-written in a more elegant and concise way?

Yes, see below.

> Do you see any potential issues?

There is code duplication and unnecessary complexity dealing with `std::cin`. Also, the function is not very generic; if you want to get a choice for a different menu you would have to write a new function.

## Reading a line with an integer in it

First, read a single line, and check if that succeeded. If not, either return some value indicating an error, or `throw` an exception. For example:

```
std::string line;

if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error while reading input");
}
```

Then try to convert it with `std::stoi()` or any of its variants, depending on the type of integer. Use the second argument to [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to know where it stopped parsing the integer, and check that this was at the end of the string:

```
try {
    size_t endpos;
    size_t value = stoi(line, &endpos);

    if (endpos == line.size()) {
        // Success!
        ...
    }
} catch (std::logic_error &) {
    // Error parsing the integer
    ...
}
```

## Make `getChoice()` more generic

You hardcoded the choices in `getChoice()`. If you have a program with multiple menus, then you would have to write different versions of `getChoice()`, duplicating a lot of code. So try to make it more generic. For example, you can have `getChoice()` take two parameters: one is a string with the title of the menu, the second is a vector of strings with the possible choices.

## Full example

Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

size_t getChoice(const std::string &title, const std::vector<std::string> &choices)
{
    std::cout << title << "\n"
              << "-------------------\n";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < choices.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ". " << choices[i] << "\n";
    }

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter choice: " << std::flush;
        std::string line;

        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not read input");
        }

        try {
            size_t endpos;
            size_t choice = stoul(line, &endpos);

            if (endpos == line.size() && choice < choices.size()) {
                return choice;
            }
        } catch (std::exception &) {
            // nothing to do here
        }

        std::cout << "Invalid choice\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    static const std::vector<std::string> choices = {
        "Add record",
        "Edit record",
        "Delete record",
        "View record",
        "view all records",
        "Exit",
    };

    size_t choice = getChoice("Main menu", choices);

    std::cout << "User chose option " << choice << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I made the option numbers start with zero, just to keep the code slightly simpler. I also used `size_t`, as it is unsigned (no need to deal with negative numbers), and it's good practice whenever you deal with indices into arrays, vectors and so on. Note that you don't have to create a named vector in `main()`, you can even pass a literal to `getChoices()`:

```
size_t choice = getChoice("Menu", {"First option", "Second option", ...});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions.  I really appreciate it.  I like all your suggestions.  In particularly, I like your suggestion to make getChoice() a generic function, using try/catch to handle errors, and using getline() to get input from the user.  I've learned quite a bit studying your example.  That's great, thanks again, cheers!